# List of System21 Tables?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am about to start working with a System21 database and I am looking to find a file definition list. From reading the GEAC System21 IBM Handbook I found a few snippets like:

- OEP40 = Sales Order Header
- INP35 = Inventory Item Master

Is there a master list anywhere?

Comment: You might ask here: http://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/system21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System i Database Catalog maintains a list of all tables / files on the system.

You can SQL query the catalog objects to get a list of tables, views, indexes, procedures, functions, etc..  The catalog objects are stored in library / schema QSYS2 and use a SYS object name prefix.  To get a list of tables for a schema, run this query:

```
select * from QSYS2.SYSTABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'supply your schema name here'
```

To get a list of most of the catalog objects, run this query:

```
select * from QSYS2.SYSTABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'QSYS2' and TABLE_NAME like 'SYS%'
```

As I recall, some of the catalog objects are SQL views instead of tables, so to find those, run this query:

```
select * from QSYS2.SYSVIEWS where OBJECT_SCHEMA = 'QSYS2' and OBJECT_NAME like 'SYS%'
```